# JSON Result Datetime assign to the textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net MVC web application, I wrote an ajax call to get the date value from the database.

Then I assign the result to the view, but it doesn't show as a DateTime value.

Can you help me to solve this issue?

This is my code

Controller

```
public JsonResult GetWorkDuration(int Id)
{
    if (Id != 0)
    {
        int workDuration = db.Services.First(x => x.Id == Id).Work_Duration_Dates;
        DateTime serviceEndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(workDuration);
        return Json(new { Success = true, EndDate = serviceEndDate });
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { Success = false });
    }

}
```

Here `serviceEndDate` contains the value as an example `10/7/2022 12:32:48 PM`

On view, this is the ajax

```
function GetWorkDuration(xVal, mapid) {
    try {
        $("#WorkDuration" + mapid).empty().trigger("changed");
        $.ajax({
            url: '../GetWorkDuration',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: { Id: xVal },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success == true) {
                    var endDate = data.EndDate;
                    document.getElementById('WorkDuration').value = endDate;
                    console.log(endDate);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
}
```

The result I assign to the

```
 @Html.EditorFor(
   model => model.Service_End_Date, 
   new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disable" ,@id="WorkDuration"} })
```

But the value is shown as

```
/Date(1665126168898)/
```

Can you help me to solve this and show the service end date as date?

### Editing

Here is a demo of the question

[image]

Comment: Please show the actual JSON that gets generated.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Hi, Please see the question again, I have added a demo of the question.

Comment: Most likely that you need to format the Date into desired date string format in JS, then assign back to the textbox. Or you may look for the *Datepicker* kind library which will auto format the date in textbox.

Comment: Please include the generated JSON as text in your question.

Comment: @YongShun I have added the datetime picker to the class. But it still the showing the value is same.  ``` @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Service_End_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control js-datepicker", @disabled = "disable" ,@id="WorkDuration"} })```

Comment: If you apply this `const picker = datepicker('#WorkDuration'); picker.setDate(endDate);` by replacing `document.getElementById('WorkDuration').value = endDate;`, does it work? I assume that you are using this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker).

Comment: @YongShun I tried your code. but then I get ``Uncaught ReferenceError: datepicker is not defined`` Error

Comment: @YongShun the library is different.

Comment: @YongShun In the controller,  I have did this ``DateTime serviceEndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(workDuration);
                string date = serviceEndDate.ToString("d");`` I Created a **string date** and converted the datetime to string and passed it to the JSON result. Then it worked.